# How to send 2 emails with only one PHP contact form

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, contacts

I'm learning PHP and coding and am looking for a way to send 2 email confirmation with this PHP code. I tried to duplicate my mail function but didn't work. I'm not sure I have to duplicate the SMTP part too or not.

What can I try next?

```
      <?php
      use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
      
if  ( isset ($_POST['name']) and isset ($_POST['email']) and isset ($_POST['message']) ){
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $rappel = $_POST['period'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $ville = $_POST['city'];
  $net = $_POST['net'];
  $tv = $_POST['tv'];
  $tel = $_POST['tel'];
  $file_attach  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $file_attach_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxx@xxx.com";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->setFrom('xxx@xxx.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('$email', '$name');
$cnt=count($_FILES['file']['name']);
   if($cnt > 0){
     for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
       $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['file']['name'][$i],'base64',$_FILES['file']['type'][$i]);
     }
   }

    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Message de votre site ' . $client . ' - ' . $name;
        //Keep it simple - don't use HTML
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        //Build a simple message body
        $mail->Body = file_get_contents('rd-mailform.tpl');

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartName} -->", "<!-- #{Name} -->"],
            ["Nom:", $_POST['name']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartPhone} -->", "<!-- #{Phone} -->"],
            ["T&#233;l&#233;phone:", $_POST['phone']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartEmail} -->", "<!-- #{Email} -->"],
            ["Email:", $_POST['email']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{StartRappel} -->", "<!-- #{Rappel} -->"],
            ["P&#233;riode de rappel:", $_POST['period']],
            $mail->Body);

        $mail->Body = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{MessageStart} -->", "<!-- #{Message} -->"],
            ["Message:", $_POST['message']],
            $mail->Body);

       $mail->Body = $mail->Body."Adresse IP de l'expéditeur: $ssIPAddress / Localisation <a href='http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php?ip=$ssIPAddress'>ici</a>, <a href='http://www.ip-tracker.org/ip-to-location.php?ip=$ssIPAddress'>ici</a> et <a href='http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ssIPAddress'>ici</a></p>";

        //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {

    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
     print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=success.php\">";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you are talking about sending the same email to multiple recipients -- for PHPMailer, use AddAddress() please

Comment: Thanks Ken. Actually I need to send a second email to customers. This one already set if for admin.

Comment: Then just send the 2nd email using another block (what actually is your problem ?)

Comment: I don't know how I should write this 2nd block. As I said in the beginning, i tried to duplicate the block and edit it, it didn't work. I don't know I missed.

Comment: One non-critical error: `$mail->addReplyTo('$email', '$name');` won't work because single quotes don't interpolate variables.

Comment: Thanks Synchro, I'll edit that :)